# Ruby on Rails beginner question : equality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm starting to know ROR and I was doing a kind of blog with articles, etc...
I did this code :

```
def show
 id = params[:id]
 list = Article.all
 is_valid = false

list.all.each do |article|
  if article.id == id
    @is_valid = true
    break
  end
end
```

As you can see, this code just wants to check if the article ID exists or not. So I'm testing equality between id and article.id (which's a model linked to the appropriated table in the database) BUT when I try to use or display @is_valid boolean I saw that article.id == id is FALSE every time, even if article.id = 2 and id = 2. I tried to think about everything that can make this occuring, but I admit I still misunderstand this.

Then I ask you if you know why this is occuring. Of course, an equality like 2 == 2 will change @is_valid to true.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: 1. You are missing an `end` at the end. 2. I don't know rails but as `params` is not passed to the method as an argument it would not seem to be visible within the method. 3. It would appear that `list.all.each do |article| ... end` could be simplified to `@is_valid = list.any? { |article| article.id == id }`. 4. You don't need to define `@is_valid` if it's not needed outside the method; just write `Article.all.any? { |article| article.id == id }` after you've obtained `id`.

Comment: I'll try it too, thank you for your help !

Comment: Hi! `is_valid` (local variable) is not the same as `@is_valid` (controller instance variable). Also `params[:id]` may be String but article.id is Integer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland for #2 in your comment above, in rails `params` is a method that comes from the controller base class and returns a memoized hash-like object (of class `ActionController::Parameters`) containing all query string and POST parameters. Not super relevant here, but knowledge for knowledge sake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe its because params[:id] it's a string and article.id it's an Integer

```
(byebug) params
{"controller"=>"admin/my_controller", "action"=>"edit", "id"=>"1"}
```

And yes it is... "id" is a string "1", so you may try this:

```
def show
 id = params[:id].to_i
 list = Article.all
 is_valid = false 

  list.all.each do |article|
    if article.id == id
      @is_valid = true
        break
      end
   end
end
```

And maybe could work.

This is the answer to your question, 
But if you want to learn a little more about Activerecord you can do this

```
Article.exists?(params[:id])
```

and that will do what you are trying to do just with a query against db.

and if you want to get just a simple article

```
record = Article.find_by(id: params[:id]) #return nil when not exist
if record # if nil will threat like false on ruby
#my code when exist
else
#my code when not exist
end
```

will work (you also can use find but find will throw an exception ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound when not exists so you have to catch that exception.

Activerecord has many ways to check this you dont need to do it by hand.

Comment: You just answered to everything and more than I expected. To use exists? methods is 100% easier, but I didn't know it so far. Thank you really much.

Comment: ActiveRecord its the part of the models in rails (for me the best part of rails) you can find a lot of methods there that will make your code better :)

Answer (score 1):

```
def show 
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end
```

This will create a database query which returns a single row. `.find` raises a `ActiveRecord::NotFound` exception if the record is not found. Rails catches this error and shows a 404 page. `Article.find_by(id: params[:id])` is the "safe" alternative that does not raise.

Your code is problematic since `list = Article.all` will load all the records out of the database which is slow and will exhaust the memory on the server if you have enough articles. Its the least effective way possible to solve the task.

If you want to just test for existence use `.exists?` or `.any?`. This creates a `COUNT` query instead of selecting the rows.

```
Article.where(title: 'Hello World').exists?
```